# pandas remove all words before a specific word and get the first n words after that specific word

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'caption':'hello this pack is for you: Jake Peralta. Thanks'})
df

caption
hello this pack is for you: Jake Peralta. Thanks
...
...
...
```

I'm trying to get the recipient's first and last name here. The format of the caption column is always the same. So delete everything before **for you:** and get the first 2(this number may change) words after **for you:**

Comment: Is your expected output is `[ Jake Peralta. Thanks]`

Comment: @Deepan no need "Thanks" only [Jake Peralta].

Comment: so you have completed the code then post the answer and close the question @Clegane

Comment: @Deepan What if I have thousands of rows like this?

Comment: It's best if you post with sample data and expected answer in detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247886/discussion-between-deepan-and-clegane).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
df.caption.apply(lambda st: st[st.find(":")+2:st.find(".")])
```

output :

```
0     Jake Peralta
Name: caption, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Takes care of leading spaces in name:

```
>>> df.caption.str.split(".").str[0].str.split(":").str[1].str.strip()

1    Jake Peralta
Name: caption, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try like this

```
df['caption'].str.split("for you: ").str[1].str.split('.').str[0]
```

output:

```
0    Jake Peralta
1      first last
```